How can i debug qemu with gdb to find out what the problem with one vector instruction implement in rvv isa
sa the title said, we just costome a qemu target on rvv isa , but here is a problem that in the vector instruction implement a err happened "[ERROR] sew:32 != index width:64
Segmentation fault (core dumped)" , how can we debug qemu to deal with this problem.
we have a test executable program that can repeat this bug,in my opnion,use gdb -g3 to debug qemu with test,and insert breakpoint on main & trans_##name (in helper.c) & decode_insn32 , and see what the args and attribute of this vector instruction implement function.  but seems that doesnt work, once qemu run to the trans_##name breakpoint,it just coredumped but the vector instruction implement fuction didnt run!
do u guys have any idea to help us? (target : rvv isa,  host:x86 isa)
hope people can help us find out where the bug is and fix it.

there's  an another question, trans_##name was written by macro define, and cant be breakpointed even if used -g3 in globle MakeFile, ( CFLAGS += -g3 ), how to make a breakpoint on trans_##name

To debug QEMU itself, run it under the host gdb in exactly the same way you would debug any other C program. If QEMU is dumping core then you can look at the backtrace in the debugger to find out why. To get a useful QEMU for debugging, pass '--enable-debug' to configure, which turns off optimisations and enables -g.

thanks, i post a unclear question. the real problem is the fuction in the custome qemu are defined by macro so i cant insert a breakpoint .
i solve this problem by inserting a line breakpoint in the fuction ,then debug to find the fuction name in backtrace.
